# python, in for loop i can iterate only with my last element

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary that contains a list of servers:

{'server1': 'RHEL 6.8', 'server2': 'RHEL 6.8', 'server3': 'RHEL 6.8', 'server4': 'RHEL 6.8'}

I want launch a `hostname` command on each node (this is a method on class).

ssh connection:

```
def ssh(self, cl_name, cmd):
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(self.cl_name, timeout=2)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)

        out = stdout.read()
        return out
    except (paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException, socket.error, paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException, socket.gaierror):
        print "server DOWN"
        return False
```

This is the method that should by run a `hostname` command on each node:

```
def get_load(self):
    for k in self.get_cluster_nodes().keys():
        print k
        cmd = "hostname"
        print self.ssh(k, cmd).rstrip()
```

This is the output:

server1 (EXAMPLE: print k)
server4 (EXAMPLE: print self.ssh(k, cmd).rstrip() )

server2
server4

server3
server4

server4
server4

I work on python 2.7.

Comment: What is your problem, you didn't mention it.

Comment: yes i mentioned, if you see the last 5 row (is the output of my .py) the results correspond only with the my last key of my dictio, the output that i expect is:
server1 server1
server2 server2
server3 server3
server4 server4

Comment: I voted to close, with the reason "unclear what you're asking", because I do not see the connection between your (strange) dictionary and your problem and, no, your comment has not helped me to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your output, everything seems fine.

You are using `self.cl_name` instead of `cl_name` which would be a parameter of your function (`k` in this case).
I think that you are calling the method from an object which has its attribute `cl_name` set to `server4`.

Old:
*Although it seems that the `hostname` command output is the same for each server, have you tried connecting manually to each servers and running `hostname` ?

If you did, the problem might come from somewhere else, like a bad value for the server IP or something.*

Comment: Hi, yes:

cat clu.txt
server1
server2
server3
server4

[root@mynode /home/user/dir]# cat clu | while read n ; do echo $n && ssh -qn $n hostname ; done
server1 server1
server2 server2
server3 server3
server4 server4

Comment: Your print shows that you are iterating through all the keys (`print k` gives you `server1 ..2 ..3 ..4`.
Have you tried to print the IP, or whatever identification you use to connect to your server in the function ?